# Backing up a MySQL database and restoring it under another name

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to do some maintenance on MySQL database data and I created a dump file with the backed up current database.

I want to restore all that data into another database called something like original_db_name_test

Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This depends on how you invoked `mysqldump`

If you used `mysqldump dbname`, then your dump contains neither `CREATE DATABASE` nor `USE DATABASE`.

Just create the database with the new name and feed the dump to `mysql -D new_dbname`.

If you used `mysqldump --database dbname`, then the dump contains `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE DATABASE` statements.

You need to comment them out or replace with `new_dbname`.

Comment: Hmmm, I did use the mysqldump command and while I do not have things like "create databasename" in my dump, I do have references to the database name in the dump.  Here is an example: "Host: localhost    Database: hiking"   ....So that probably means that I have to rename the references to my original dbname to the new one.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Genadinik: the things you are referring to seem to be comments.

Comment: yes after looking more closely at the file you are right.  It was comments :)

Comment: By the way, the current dump file has things like this for the tables: "ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=92 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;" should I change the latin1 to utf-8 and that should do the trick?  Or that will only effect the tables?  How do I change it for the entire database as well?

Comment: @Genadinik: unless you used explicit charset definitions for the individual columns, changing the table `DEFAULT CHARSET` to `UTF8` will create all the columns in the table as `UTF8` and the data will go as `UTF8`.

Comment: Correct `mysqldump` option is [--databases](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases) with the `s`

Answer (score 2):

mysql -u usernamehere -p original_db_name_test < yourdumpfilehere.sql

Comment: I think this would not be right because the original dump file has the names of the original database name and needs to have the names of the new database name.

Comment: @jschorr because it depends on the parameters how your mysqldump was created.

Answer (score 1):

If you used mysqldump to create the dump file, simply:

1. Create a new database (use the mysqladmin command line tool - `"mysqladmin create [new database name]`").
2. Edit the dump file to add a "`USE [new database name];`" at the top. (There *might* be an existing use statement that's commented out, so you can change this and un-comment it.)
3. Import the dump into the new table via "`mysql -u <user name> -p < [dump file name]`".

Incidentally, when creating a dump via mysqldump, I'd be tempted to use the "--add-drop-table" option, as this will cull any existing table with the same name prior to issuing the table creation statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'MySQL Workbench' Application and do this with a nice gui